# Numpy.selectand assign new colum in df with condition from values of two column

Tags: pandas, numpy

```
df  = df.assign[test  = np.select[df.trs = 'iw' & df.rp == 'yu'],[1,0],'null']
```

I want `if df.trs ==` iw' and df.rp == 'yu'` than new column should be created should be 0 else  1  only for condotion fullfilling row not every row

I tried no.slect and with condition array. But not getting desired output

Comment: Your syntax is fully incorrect, you used square brackets in place of parentheses.

Comment: Can you provide an example of input / output?

Answer (score -1):

You don't need [`numpy.select`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.select.html), a simple boolean operator is sufficient:

```
df['test'] = (df['trs'].eq('iw') & df['rp'].eq('yu')).astype(int)
```

If you really want to use `numpy`, this would require [`numpy.where`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html):

```
df['test'] = np.where(df['trs'].eq('iw') & df['rp'].eq('yu'), 1, 0)
```